# How do I change the line type for trendlines (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the following command to create my figure:

```
AfterLatency <- ggplot(
  After,
  aes(
    x = After$X7.Days.Time.in.Blank,
    y = After$X7.Days.Latency.to.Leave,
    shape = factor(Treatment),
    color = factor(Treatment)
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  xlab("Time in Blank (s)") +
  ylab("Latency to leave (s)")
```

I tried this : `AfterLatency + scale_linetype_manual("Treatment", values=c("Control"=2, "Sertraline"=4))`

and also tried to include the `linetype` command within the geom_smooth but neither worked.

I was wondering how can I change one of the trendlines to dashed?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post an image of data, I believe that most people do not want to transcribe data from an image into something to test. It is much better to post something that we can copy from here and paste directly into an R session, such as with `dput(head(x))`. I suggest you read about [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, just shared it so whoever is trying to help can see the headings of the columns, but you're right I should've copied that instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `linetype` as an aesthetic of `geom_smooth`.

```
geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE, aes(linetype = Treatment))
```

---

Also, there is no need for `After$`. That is useful though if using other mappings in the geoms.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with using `lty` as a parameter to `aes` in `ggplot`:

```
AfterLatency <- ggplot(
  After,
  aes(
    x = After$X7.Days.Time.in.Blank,
    y = After$X7.Days.Latency.to.Leave,
    shape = factor(Treatment),
    color = factor(Treatment),
    lty=factor(Treatment)
  )
)
```